# Suddenly unable to load library(Seurat)

Tags: r, macos-monterey, seurat

This issue has only started today, this morning all my libraries in my RStudio ran without issue.

```
 > library (Seurat)
```

This is the error I get:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Seurat’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘httr’
```

When I try to install "httr" with:

```
> install.packages("httr")
```

I get the following error:

```
There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
     binary source needs_compilation
httr  1.4.5  1.4.6             FALSE

installing the source package ‘httr’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/httr_1.4.6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 157621 bytes (153 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 153 KB

/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/Rcmd: line 40: sed: command not found
export BIBINPUTS=".:/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/share/texmf/bibtex/bib:"
export BSTINPUTS=".:/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/share/texmf/bibtex/bst:"
export CLICOLOR_FORCE="1"
export COMMAND_MODE="unix2003"
export DISPLAY="/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.mvl13grjQD/org.xquartz:0"
export EDITOR="vi"
export GIT_ASKPASS="rpostback-askpass"
export HOME="/Users/kj15161"
export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
export LN_S="ln -s"
export LOGNAME="kj15161"
export MAKE="make"
export MPLENGINE="tkAgg"
export OLDPWD
export PAGER="/usr/bin/less"
export PATH="/opt/anaconda3/bin/python"
export PWD="/Users/kj15161/Desktop/Moxon_May"
export PYTHONIOENCODING="utf-8"
export RMARKDOWN_MATHJAX_PATH="/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/resources/mathjax-27"
export RSTUDIO="1"
export RSTUDIO_CLI_HYPERLINKS="true"
export RSTUDIO_CONSOLE_COLOR="256"
export RSTUDIO_CONSOLE_WIDTH="134"
export RSTUDIO_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="/var/folders/t3/fr59bpbs2237pzbbg04sy3280000gn/T/rstudio-fallback-library-path-ROntal"
export RSTUDIO_PANDOC="/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/quarto/bin/tools"
export RSTUDIO_PROGRAM_MODE="desktop"
export RSTUDIO_SESSION_PID="1942"
export RSTUDIO_SESSION_PORT="57704"
export RSTUDIO_USER_IDENTITY="kj15161"
export RSTUDIO_WINUTILS="bin/winutils"
export RS_PPM_FD_READ="8"
export RS_PPM_FD_WRITE="9"
export RS_RPOSTBACK_PATH="/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/rpostback"
export RS_SHARED_SECRET="b4fcbe4f-ba30-453b-b170-ecd69eb0db06"
export R_ARCH=""
export R_BROWSER="/usr/bin/open"
export R_BZIPCMD="/usr/bin/bzip2"
export R_CLI_HAS_HYPERLINK_IDE_HELP="true"
export R_CLI_HAS_HYPERLINK_IDE_RUN="true"
export R_CLI_HAS_HYPERLINK_IDE_VIGNETTE="true"
export R_CMD="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/Rcmd"
export R_DOC_DIR="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/doc"
export R_GZIPCMD="/usr/bin/gzip"
export R_HOME="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources"
export R_INCLUDE_DIR="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include"
export R_LIBS="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library"
export R_LIBS_SITE="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/site-library"
export R_LIBS_USER="/Users/kj15161/Library/R/x86_64/4.2/library"
export R_MAX_VSIZE="100GB"
export R_OSTYPE="unix"
export R_PAPERSIZE="a4"
export R_PDFVIEWER="/usr/bin/open"
export R_PLATFORM="x86_64-apple-darwin17.0"
export R_PRINTCMD="lpr"
export R_QPDF="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/qpdf"
export R_RD4PDF="times,inconsolata,hyper"
export R_SESSION_TMPDIR="/var/folders/t3/fr59bpbs2237pzbbg04sy3280000gn/T//RtmpJQDUIt"
export R_SHARE_DIR="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/share"
export R_STRIP_SHARED_LIB="strip -x"
export R_STRIP_STATIC_LIB="strip -S"
export R_SYSTEM_ABI="macos,gcc,gxx,gfortran,gfortran"
export R_TEXI2DVICMD="/usr/local/bin/texi2dvi"
export R_UNZIPCMD="/usr/bin/unzip"
export R_VERSION="4.2.1"
export R_ZIPCMD="/usr/bin/zip"
export SED="/usr/bin/sed"
export SHELL="/bin/zsh"
export SHLVL="2"
export SSH_ASKPASS="rpostback-askpass"
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.HWkivOZQaV/Listeners"
export TAR="/usr/bin/tar"
export TERM="xterm-256color"
export TEXINPUTS=".:/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/share/texmf/tex/latex:"
export TMPDIR="/var/folders/t3/fr59bpbs2237pzbbg04sy3280000gn/T/"
export TZDIR="/var/db/timezone/zoneinfo"
export USER="kj15161"
export XPC_FLAGS="0x0"
export XPC_SERVICE_NAME="application.org.rstudio.RStudio.13546952.13546972"
export __CFBundleIdentifier="org.rstudio.RStudio"
export __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING="0x1F5:0x0:0x0"
* installing *source* package ‘httr’ ...
** package ‘httr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** demo
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
sh: rm: command not found
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
sh: rm: command not found
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
sh: rm: command not found
sh: mv: command not found
Warning in system(paste("mv -f", shQuote(instdir), shQuote(dirname(final_instdir)))) :
  error in running command
ERROR:   moving to final location failed
sh: rm: command not found
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘httr’ had non-zero exit status
```

The downloaded source packages are in:

```
private/var/folders/t3/fr59bpbs2237pzbbg04sy3280000gn/T/RtmpkJ97Mc/downloaded_packages
```

I am running R version `4.2.1` (2022-06-23) -- "Funny-Looking Kid" on MacOS Monterey version 12.4.

Initially thought it might be an Xcode issue, however, I do seem to have this installed already as shown in my terminal:

```
(base) user@laptop ~ % xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

Comment: Errors such as `line 40: sed: command not found` or `sh: rm: command not found` point to your `/bin/` directory not being in your PATH environmental variable.

The following line seems to be the issue: `export PATH="/opt/anaconda3/bin/python"`
Are you setting the PATH variable manually somewhere, e.g. in `~/.zshrc`?

Comment: I could very well be, examining the content of ~/.zshrc reveals the following:      
  # >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<

Comment: Is this something I can/should change?

Comment: The block of text you found in your `.zshrc` file was added by conda and is not the source of your issue. It appears that your PATH variable is being set to empty somewhere else and then the `conda init` code adds the path to the conda executables. Since the install errors come from sh shell and sh on macOS is aliased to bash, you can also look whether either the `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` files contain anything that is modifying PATH.

Comment: really appreciate your help gl-eb. Sadly both of those (~/.profile and ~/.bashrc) are empty? Any ideas what else might be doing this? Cannot fathom why this has happened all of a sudden.

Comment: I'm mostly guessing at this point. I notice that you have the base conda environment activated. Could you tell me what entering `echo $PATH` in your terminal returns? Also, does this output change after deactivating conda using `conda deactivate base`?

Comment: I think you're onto something though. I have come across this before.

 (base) user@laptop ~ % echo $PATH
/opt/anaconda3/bin:/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/munki:/opt/X11/bin

Comment: It didnt like conda deactivate base. But conda deactivate gives me the same output.

echo $PATH
/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/munki:/opt/X11/bin

Comment: Okay, that looks as it should. Now we need to figure out why R could not find sed, rm, mv etc. when installing the package. Have you restarted RStudio or even your computer since the problem often occured. Maybe something weird happened in your current R session which messed with PATH.

Alternatively, does `~/.Rprofile` exist and does it contain anything related to PATH?

Comment: OK i think i may have solved this. But at present im still a bit lost as to whats going on.

running:

> install.packages("httr", type="binary")

has sorted the whole thing, and now allows me to run library(seurat).

Not a scooby why. Any thoughts welcome!

Comment: Great minds gl-eb. I have indeed restarted Rstudio, the computer. I do not have ~/.Rprofile in my home folder (Of course using ls -a).

Comment: A binary is a precompiled version of the package. You do not need Xcode command line tools to install them. So at least you now have a workaround. Regarding the issue, do you have an `~/.Renviron` file? Both `.Rprofile` and `.Renviron` could also be inside of the folder where your R project is located (the working directory).

Comment: Interesting. Yes I do have ~/.Renviron

user@laptop ~ % cat .Renviron 
R_MAX_VSIZE=100GB

Comment: Nope, that's not it either. The long list of `export VARIABLE` statements in your error looks like a dump of all environmental variables like you would get from running `Sys.getenv()` in R. But I'm running out of ideas where exactly your PATH variable is set and why it is not the same as in the terminal (it is in my case). Reinstalling R could be an option, though you might have to reinstall all packages after that. Ultimately, binaries will be available for all CRAN packages, they just might come with a bit of a delay after a new package version is released (as in this case)

Comment: I'll keep having a think about it. For now at least I can get some work done. Many thanks again gl-eb. 

Out of curiosity what should my path be set to if I do find this?

Comment: Somewhere within R your PATH is being set to `PATH="/opt/anaconda3/bin/python"`. Instead it should be similar to what you got when running `echo $PATH` in the terminal. The PATH environmental variable dictates which command line tools can be found by looking at the specified locations. The package install fails because the rools sed, rm and mv can't be found (they're probably located at `/usr/`)

Comment: Brilliant. I'll keep digging. Have a great day, I hope I can return the favor one day!

Comment: Ok while this did help for a short while, I dont think I've really fixed the problem. As im now in the situation where many packages require GenomeDBINfo and im stuck as to get it working again.

Comment: Some packages require a Fortran compiler in addition to Xcode. Read the top paragraph on [this page](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools/) on how to install it. Make sure to restart the R session after installing it. If that does not work, I would go for a reinstall of R.