# Do I have Rstudio Path variable problem? Unable to load certain libraries

Tags: r, rstudio, macos-monterey

I began with this issue
Using MacOS Monterey

[Suddenly unable to load library(Seurat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76209893/suddenly-unable-to-load-libraryseurat)

and managed as you can see here a temporary fix,
Sadly im now stuck back at what feels like square one. I cannot seem to load libraries that previously (2 days ago) were working.

```
> library(SingleR)
Loading required package: SummarizedExperiment
Loading required package: GenomicRanges
Loading required package: GenomeInfoDb
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘GenomeInfoDb’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 there is no package called ‘GenomeInfoDbData’
Error: package ‘GenomeInfoDb’ could not be loaded
In addition: Warning messages:
1: package ‘GenomicRanges’ was built under R version 4.2.2 
2: package ‘GenomeInfoDb’ was built under R version 4.2.2 
> install.packages("GenomeInfoDbData")
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘GenomeInfoDbData’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
> BiocManager::install("GenomeInfoDbData")
'getOption("repos")' replaces Bioconductor standard repositories, see 'help("repositories", package =
"BiocManager")' for details.
Replacement repositories:
    CRAN: https://cran.rstudio.com/
Bioconductor version 3.15 (BiocManager 1.30.20), R 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
Installing package(s) 'GenomeInfoDbData'
installing the source package ‘GenomeInfoDbData’

trying URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.15/data/annotation/src/contrib/GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.8.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 11512907 bytes (11.0 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 11.0 MB

/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/Rcmd: line 40: sed: command not found
export BIBINPUTS=".:/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/share/texmf/bibtex/bib:"
export BSTINPUTS=".:/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/share/texmf/bibtex/bst:"
export CLICOLOR_FORCE="1"
export COMMAND_MODE="unix2003"
export DISPLAY="/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.sPVItq2YOM/org.xquartz:0"
export EDITOR="vi"
export GIT_ASKPASS="rpostback-askpass"
export HOME="/Users/kj15161"
export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
export LN_S="ln -s"
export LOGNAME="kj15161"
export MAKE="make"
export MPLENGINE="tkAgg"
export OLDPWD
export PAGER="/usr/bin/less"
export PATH="/opt/anaconda3/bin/python"
export PWD="/Users/kj15161/Desktop"
export PYTHONIOENCODING="utf-8"
export RMARKDOWN_MATHJAX_PATH="/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/resources/mathjax-27"
export RSTUDIO="1"
export RSTUDIO_CLI_HYPERLINKS="true"
export RSTUDIO_CONSOLE_COLOR="256"
export RSTUDIO_CONSOLE_WIDTH="111"
export RSTUDIO_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="/var/folders/t3/fr59bpbs2237pzbbg04sy3280000gn/T/rstudio-fallback-library-path-NYN7tT"
export RSTUDIO_PANDOC="/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/quarto/bin/tools"
export RSTUDIO_PROGRAM_MODE="desktop"
export RSTUDIO_SESSION_PID="29412"
export RSTUDIO_SESSION_PORT="61619"
export RSTUDIO_USER_IDENTITY="kj15161"
export RSTUDIO_WINUTILS="bin/winutils"
export RS_PPM_FD_READ="11"
export RS_PPM_FD_WRITE="43"
export RS_RPOSTBACK_PATH="/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/rpostback"
export RS_SHARED_SECRET="939d8d29-a0a4-4bb9-91e1-e3c6a31f232a"
export R_ARCH=""
export R_BROWSER="/usr/bin/open"
export R_BZIPCMD="/usr/bin/bzip2"
export R_CLI_HAS_HYPERLINK_IDE_HELP="true"
export R_CLI_HAS_HYPERLINK_IDE_RUN="true"
export R_CLI_HAS_HYPERLINK_IDE_VIGNETTE="true"
export R_CMD="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/Rcmd"
export R_DOC_DIR="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/doc"
export R_GZIPCMD="/usr/bin/gzip"
export R_HOME="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources"
export R_INCLUDE_DIR="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include"
export R_LIBS="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library"
export R_LIBS_SITE="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/site-library"
export R_LIBS_USER="/Users/kj15161/Library/R/x86_64/4.2/library"
export R_MAX_VSIZE="100GB"
export R_OSTYPE="unix"
export R_PAPERSIZE="a4"
export R_PDFVIEWER="/usr/bin/open"
export R_PLATFORM="x86_64-apple-darwin17.0"
export R_PRINTCMD="lpr"
export R_QPDF="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/qpdf"
export R_RD4PDF="times,inconsolata,hyper"
export R_SESSION_TMPDIR="/var/folders/t3/fr59bpbs2237pzbbg04sy3280000gn/T//Rtmp6XpOgk"
export R_SHARE_DIR="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/share"
export R_STRIP_SHARED_LIB="strip -x"
export R_STRIP_STATIC_LIB="strip -S"
export R_SYSTEM_ABI="macos,gcc,gxx,gfortran,gfortran"
export R_TEXI2DVICMD="/usr/local/bin/texi2dvi"
export R_UNZIPCMD="/usr/bin/unzip"
export R_VERSION="4.2.1"
export R_ZIPCMD="/usr/bin/zip"
export SED="/usr/bin/sed"
export SHELL="/bin/zsh"
export SHLVL="2"
export SSH_ASKPASS="rpostback-askpass"
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.S3NhuUQbdx/Listeners"
export TAR="/usr/bin/tar"
export TERM="xterm-256color"
export TEXINPUTS=".:/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/share/texmf/tex/latex:"
export TMPDIR="/var/folders/t3/fr59bpbs2237pzbbg04sy3280000gn/T/"
export TZDIR="/var/db/timezone/zoneinfo"
export USER="kj15161"
export XPC_FLAGS="0x0"
export XPC_SERVICE_NAME="application.org.rstudio.RStudio.13546952.13546972"
export __CFBundleIdentifier="org.rstudio.RStudio"
export __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING="0x1F5:0x0:0x0"
* installing *source* package ‘GenomeInfoDbData’ ...
** using staged installation
** data
** inst
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
sh: rm: command not found
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
sh: rm: command not found
sh: mv: command not found
Warning in system(paste("mv -f", shQuote(instdir), shQuote(dirname(final_instdir)))) :
  error in running command
ERROR:   moving to final location failed
sh: rm: command not found

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/t3/fr59bpbs2237pzbbg04sy3280000gn/T/Rtmp6XpOgk/downloaded_packages’
Old packages: 'pscl', 'scattermore', 'spatstat.geom'
Update all/some/none? [a/s/n]: 
n
Warning message:
In install.packages(...) :
  installation of package ‘GenomeInfoDbData’ had non-zero exit status
```

A few people have suggested its a PATH issue but examining .Renviron only reveals

(base) user@laptop ~ % cat .Renviron
R_MAX_VSIZE=100GB

I dont have .Rprofile

This may be of use?
(base) user@laptop ~ % echo $PATH
/opt/anaconda3/bin:/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/munki:/opt/X11/bin

in Rstudio

```
> Sys.getenv()
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING          0x1F5:0x0:0x0
__CFBundleIdentifier             org.rstudio.RStudio
CLICOLOR_FORCE                   1
COMMAND_MODE                     unix2003
DISPLAY                          /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.sPVItq2YOM/org.xquartz:0
DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH       /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib:/Users/kj15161/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/lib:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server:/var/folders/t3/fr59bpbs2237pzbbg04sy3280000gn/T/rstudio-fallback-library-path-NYN7tT
EDITOR                           vi
GIT_ASKPASS                      rpostback-askpass
HOME                             /Users/kj15161
LANG                             en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE                         en_US.UTF-8
LN_S                             ln -s
LOGNAME                          kj15161
MAKE                             make
MPLENGINE                        tkAgg
PAGER                            /usr/bin/less
PATH                             /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/munki:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/kj15161/Applications/quarto/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/texbin:/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/quarto/bin:/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS
PYTHONIOENCODING                 utf-8
R_BROWSER                        /usr/bin/open
R_BZIPCMD                        /usr/bin/bzip2
R_CLI_HAS_HYPERLINK_IDE_HELP     true
R_CLI_HAS_HYPERLINK_IDE_RUN      true
R_CLI_HAS_HYPERLINK_IDE_VIGNETTE
                                 true
R_DOC_DIR                        /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/doc
R_GZIPCMD                        /usr/bin/gzip
R_HOME                           /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
R_INCLUDE_DIR                    /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include
R_LIBS_SITE                      /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/site-library
R_LIBS_USER                      /Users/kj15161/Library/R/x86_64/4.2/library
R_MAX_VSIZE                      100GB
R_PAPERSIZE                      a4
R_PDFVIEWER                      /usr/bin/open
R_PLATFORM                       x86_64-apple-darwin17.0
R_PRINTCMD                       lpr
R_QPDF                           /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/qpdf
R_RD4PDF                         times,inconsolata,hyper
R_SESSION_TMPDIR                 /var/folders/t3/fr59bpbs2237pzbbg04sy3280000gn/T//Rtmp6XpOgk
R_SHARE_DIR                      /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/share
R_STRIP_SHARED_LIB               strip -x
R_STRIP_STATIC_LIB               strip -S
R_SYSTEM_ABI                     macos,gcc,gxx,gfortran,gfortran
R_TEXI2DVICMD                    /usr/local/bin/texi2dvi
R_UNZIPCMD                       /usr/bin/unzip
R_ZIPCMD                         /usr/bin/zip
RMARKDOWN_MATHJAX_PATH           /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/resources/mathjax-27
RS_PPM_FD_READ                   11
RS_PPM_FD_WRITE                  43
RS_RPOSTBACK_PATH                /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/rpostback
RSTUDIO                          1
RSTUDIO_CLI_HYPERLINKS           true
RSTUDIO_CONSOLE_COLOR            256
RSTUDIO_CONSOLE_WIDTH            111
RSTUDIO_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH    /var/folders/t3/fr59bpbs2237pzbbg04sy3280000gn/T/rstudio-fallback-library-path-NYN7tT
RSTUDIO_PANDOC                   /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/quarto/bin/tools
RSTUDIO_PROGRAM_MODE             desktop
RSTUDIO_SESSION_PID              29412
RSTUDIO_SESSION_PORT             61619
RSTUDIO_USER_IDENTITY            kj15161
RSTUDIO_WINUTILS                 bin/winutils
SED                              /usr/bin/sed
SHELL                            /bin/zsh
SSH_ASKPASS                      rpostback-askpass
SSH_AUTH_SOCK                    /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.S3NhuUQbdx/Listeners
TAR                              /usr/bin/tar
TERM                             xterm-256color
TMPDIR                           /var/folders/t3/fr59bpbs2237pzbbg04sy3280000gn/T/
TZDIR                            /var/db/timezone/zoneinfo
USER                             kj15161
XPC_FLAGS                        0x0
XPC_SERVICE_NAME                 application.org.rstudio.RStudio.13546952.13546972
```

At this point I'm wondering if uninstalling Rstudio and reinstalling would help at all?
Any help appreciated, thanks

see above attempted

Comment: The error suggests you are working with an old version of R. What version do you have installed?

Comment: It's also odd that it said `sed: command not found`. If you run `which sed` in a terminal, does it return a path like `/usr/bin/sed`?

Comment: Hi im running R 4.2.1 which I wouldnt have thought would be too old?

yes I get /usr/bin/sed